# veth pair from a single physical nic

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

I'm trying to setup an all-in-one Openstack kolla on a CentOS-7 with a single physical NIC, but I cannot manage to setup the network for VMs to get ips on the same LAN as the host.

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/kolla/mitaka/quickstart.html),

> The “neutron_external_interface” variable is the interface that will be used for the external bridge in Neutron. Without this bridge the deployment instance traffic will be unable to access the rest of the Internet. In the case of a single interface on a machine, a veth pair may be used where one end of the veth pair is listed here and the other end is in a bridge on the system.

Hence how can I configure this persistent veth pair on my CentOS7 platform?

Comment: It would be very good to see what you have done so far and what is it exactly that you want (what subnets exists where and how you get the IP's for the vnet's, do you want them to be static or dynamic).

Comment: Even though it's not sufficient to get kolla Openstack working as I wish (with my VMs getting ips on the same physical network as my host physical interface), I do have found how to setup fully [virtual interfaces](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333912/virtual-interface-different-mac-bootproto-etc-on-the-same-subnet-as-physic/334101#334101)