# virtual interface (different mac, bootproto, etc..) on the same subnet as physical NIC

Tags: centos, networking, rhel

In short I have 1 physical NIC, I would need to simulate a 2nd (virtual) interface (different MAC, BOOTPROTO, etc..) which would be connected to the same subnet as the physical NIC.

I've tried many different setup but unsuccessfully so far. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You meant eth0:1 with different MAC.You should use MACChanger to change MAC address.Actually you can create eth0:1 using command line and put it on /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

Comment: MACChanger is more a trick than an actual solution. Anyway, I've found a suitable solution

Comment: When you created virtual interface.You didnt need to change MAC address.Virtual interface still works fine with Same MAC address.Changing MAC address just wanted to cheat network security. Some switches L3 can block it based on MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to setup fully virtual interfaces [here](https://github.com/larsks/initscripts-macvlan). Hence

Create both `ifup-macvlan` and `ifdown-macvlan` scripts at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`
Create your `ifcfg-veth0` (with the name you want)

```
DEVICE="veth0"
DEVICETYPE="macvlan"
TYPE="macvtap"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
MACADDR="AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL"
MACVLAN_PARENT="enp0s31f6"
```

Then

- customize `BOOTPROTO` to static/dhcp
- set `MACADDR` to the dummy value you want
- set `MACVLAN_PARENT` to the proper physical interface

Comment: You are funny.Because you created virtual interface as dhcp client.So DHCP server should provide 2 IP addresses to your network interface.You used it for what's purpose?

Comment: My original goal is as in this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333901/veth-pair-from-a-single-physical-nic/334100#334100): to setup an all-in-one openstack platform, it is needed to have 2 physical NIC, which I do not have. Hence, I can simulate this 2nd NIC this way. The `dhcp` was just there as an example, but I do not even need to have an IP address on this interface, I use it with `BOOTPROTO="none"`. Unfortunatelly, it's not sufficient to get my Openstack install to work as expected...

Comment: BOOTPROTO="static" when you used static IP address.